# unrecognized selector sent With NSNotifications

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4, xcode4.2

I'm using NSNotifications in a ViewController to update a UILabel in another ViewController by pressing a button :

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
...
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateLabel:)
         name:@"LABELUPDATENOTIFICATION" object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"LABELUPDATENOTIFICATION" object:@"test"]; 
...
```

And the code that receipt the String (@"test") :

```
- (void)updateLabel:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSString *updatedText = (NSString*)[notification object];
    [details setText:updatedText];
}
```

It gives me an arror when I press the button (when the first code is executed) and the second 
code is highlited with an error: "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Thanks to help me, I don't really understand  notifications...

A second question could be how send a second notification to update a second UILabel in the same Controller...

MANY THANKS!

**EDIT:
HERE'S THE ERROR TRACE:**

```
2012-01-03 16:14:43.054 emars[3749:b303] -[ThirdViewController updateLabel:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x685a0a0
2012-01-03 16:14:43.055 emars[3749:b303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ThirdViewController updateLabel:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x685a0a0'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00fb45a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01108313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00fb60bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00f25966 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00f25522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
...
```

**EDIT 2 :**

```
NSDictionary *myDictionnary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"details",@"details de l'installation",@"recapitulatif",@"recapitulatif de l'installe",nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateLabel:)
         name:@"LABELUPDATENOTIFICATION" object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"LABELUPDATENOTIFICATION" object:self userInfo:myDictionnary];
```

and in the other class :

```
- (void)updateLabel:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSDictionary *dictionnary = (NSDictionary*)[notification object];
    [details setText:[dictionnary objectForKey:@"adetails"]];
    [recapitulatif setText:[dictionnary objectForKey:@"recapitulatif"]];
}
```

I have two errors ; a cute SIGABRT and :

```
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x683d630
2012-01-03 17:37:21.783 emars[6288:b303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ThirdViewController updateLabel:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x683d630'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00fb45a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01108313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00fb60bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00f25966 ___forwarding___ + 966
...
```

THANKS for your help !!!

Comment: Which object is receiving the unrecopgnized selector - please add your console contents to the question :)

Comment: (And, though I doubt this will help your bug, the object property when you post a notification is for the object which is _sending_ the notification, not for some data. If you want to send data with the notification, use the userInfo parameter).

Answer (score 3):

You are using the post notification method incorrectly. the `object:` argument is the object that posts the notification. You've given that object as `@"test"`. This string object should not be posting any notifications. What you need to be doing is something along the lines of

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"LABELUPDATENOTIFICATION" object:self userInfo:aDictionary];
```

This `userInfo` should be an `NSDictionary`, and is how you pass objects through a notification. You can use the same notification to pass the text for both the labels. Just construct the dictionary with the strings.

```
aDictionary=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"test1",@"label1",@"test2",@"label2",nil];
```

**EDIT**
Right, you still seem to have a misunderstanding of how notifications work. Let's say you have two view controllers VC1 and VC2. If VC1 is going to post a notification with the values for the labels(which are present in VC2), it should not be the observer. You've posted it correctly but your statement

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateLabel:)
     name:@"LABELUPDATENOTIFICATION" object:nil];
```

should not be in VC1. Or rather, as @dean Wombourne said, you should add the other View Controller(VC2) as the observer. The reason for your crash is you are adding VC1 as observer and it does not implement `updateLabel:`. I would guess you donn't have a reference for VC2 object. So just cut and paste the add observer code in `viewDidLoad` of VC2.

Comment: You're 100% right but @"anyString" is still an object so it should just be very misleading to the receiver of the notification, it shouldn't cause a crash . . .

Comment: @MadhavanRP : Thanks !!! I've updated the initial post.. I've updated the code but it still crash :'(

Comment: I had a different configuration, but the answer lead me to the problem: I had object:nil instead of object:self

Answer (score 1):

The error trace says that an object `ThirdViewController` recieved the selector `updateLabel:`

The `updateLabel:` method in your question looks OK but I bet it's in the wrong class :)

Try this instead :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:otherViewController selector:@selector(updateLabel:) name:@"LABELUPDATENOTIFICATION" object:nil];
```

In your question you are asking your notification to be sent to `self`, which doesn't have an `updateLabel:` method. You need to the notificationCenter which object wants to receive the notification.

Comment: OK, many thanks, I begin to understand. the app still crash (I've updated the post... the second edit ^^)

Comment: You're still sending `self` when you add an observer - you need to register the same class as the method is on, otherwise how would the NotificationCenter know which object to send the notification to? My answer replaces `self` with `otherViewController` :)